Dry-running extrinsic using Chopsticks on command line "length less than remainder, expected at least 133, found 91"
I'm trying to test XCM governance proposals using Chopsticks but running into issues. I've cloned and compiled Chopsticks within GitBash on Windows. However, when I try to dry run it with an extrinsic I receive an Error message Extrinsic: length less than remainder, expected at least 133, found 91 that I don't know how to overcome.
> npx @acala-network/chopsticks@latest dry-run -c hydradx --extrinsic=0x0d020c4101090000000110270000102700000d0301017369626cd60700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003b0209000000000000ffcf8529967e7704000000000041010900000001f401000010270000
@polkadot/types-create has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 10.12.6     node_modules/@polkadot/types-create/cjs
        cjs 10.13.1     node_modules/@polkadot/types-known/node_modules/@polkadot/types-create/cjs
@polkadot/types-codec has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 10.12.6     node_modules/@polkadot/types-codec/cjs
        cjs 10.13.1     node_modules/@polkadot/types-known/node_modules/@polkadot/types-codec/cjs
[04:40:11.391] INFO: Loading config file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AcalaNetwork/chopsticks/master/configs/hydradx.yml
    app: "chopsticks"
chopsticks dry-run

Dry run an extrinsic

Options:
<<< clipped help text printout for brevity >>>

Error: createType(GenericExtrinsic):: Extrinsic: length less than remainder, expected at least 133, found 91
    at createTypeUnsafe (/home/spaz/.npm/_npx/81ad9c881cb83600/node_modules/@polkadot/types-create/cjs/create/type.js:54:22)
    at TypeRegistry.createType (/home/spaz/.npm/_npx/81ad9c881cb83600/node_modules/@polkadot/types/cjs/create/registry.js:224:52)
    at dryRunExtrinsic (/home/spaz/.npm/_npx/81ad9c881cb83600/node_modules/@acala-network/chopsticks-core/dist/cjs/blockchain/block-builder.js:377:24)
    at async Blockchain.dryRunExtrinsic (/home/spaz/.npm/_npx/81ad9c881cb83600/node_modules/@acala-network/chopsticks-core/dist/cjs/blockchain/index.js:321:41)
    at async dryRunExtrinsic (/home/spaz/.npm/_npx/81ad9c881cb83600/node_modules/@acala-network/chopsticks/dist/cjs/plugins/dry-run/dry-run-extrinsic.js:26:38)
    at async Object.handler (/home/spaz/.npm/_npx/81ad9c881cb83600/node_modules/@acala-network/chopsticks/dist/cjs/plugins/dry-run/cli.js:45:13)

